# Sort by subquery where another column matches the id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following table

```
ID | tbl | reply |   time
--- ----- ------- -----------
1  | blue|   0   |   01:00
--- ----- ------- -----------
2  | red |   1   |   01:05
--- ----- ------- -----------
3  | pink|   1   |   11:11
--- ----- ------- -----------
4  | pink|   0   |   22:22
--- ----- ------- -----------
5  | pink|   4   |   00:03
--- ----- ------- -----------
```

The reply refers to the ID column so ID and reply have a connection. ID is the parent of reply. When `reply=0` then it means that we have selected a parent row else it is just the reply.

At the moment I have this simple mysql query in order to select only the parents

```
SELECT tbl, time FROM table WHERE reply=0 ORDER BY time ASC
```

Which will select first the `ID=1` and then the `ID=4`

What I want is to be able to ORDER the parents by the time of the childrens but not to show the childrens. So in the above example just because `ID=5` has a time of 0:03 then the `ID=4` should appear first and then `ID=1`

Any ideas how to do this except from creating another table?
If it is better maybe any php ideas on how to do this?

Thank you very much

Comment: So get the parents with the most recent children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My SQL is a bit rusty, but:

```
SELECT t.tbl, t.time 
FROM table t 
WHERE t.reply=0 
ORDER BY 
(SELECT MAX(time) FROM table WHERE reply = t.id) DESC,
t.time DESC
```

The trick is to give the main query table a name (`t` in this example) - you can then reference it in the subquery without the server getting confused.

I know this might just be your example, but you'd be best storing your time column as a DATETIME or even a UNIX timestamp (in an INT field). You'll need the date, so that something posted yesterday at 23:00 isn't seen as more recent than something posted today at 15:00

Comment: Yeah this is my example actually and I'm storing as datetime :) I'll try it though and let you know if it worked!! Thank you very much

Comment: That did the trick :D Thank you very very much :) Can I ask though why do we take SELECT MAX instead of simple select?

Comment: `MAX` just returns the maximum value. Alternatively, you could do `SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1`, but it's not nearly as concise.

Comment: Is it possible if there is no children to sort by the parent comment time???  It's too complicated isn't it?

Comment: No what I mean is to compare by the parent time not the children time. If I'm not mistaken this will sort those with children first and then those with parent.

Comment: Just reorder the sort criteria